# how to repeat click event in jquery from the beginning as if nothing happened

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

I want to repeat the same function every time I click in the anchor tag but with new results. for example I have 3 items 
a = 0 , b = 0 , c = 1  when  I click in th anchor tag for a , b , c  I see  in th console that : a = 1 ,b = 1 , c = 0 for once and every time I click on these items the same results appear in the console ( a = 1 , b = 1 , c = 0) but when I reload the page and click on the items then it works perfectly so when I click on a it changes to 0 again and the same thing for the rest two items so (  when I click again after refresh the page : b = 0, c =1)  Now... I want to do that without reloading the page so when I click on the item a ( a = 0 for example) it should change to ( a = 1 ) click again ( then a = 0 ) and thanks in advance

/////////// my jquery ///////////////////

```
  $('.admin-btn').on("click",function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var userId = event.target.parentNode.parentNode.childNodes[1].textContent;
        var admin = 0;
        var isAdmin = event.target.dataset['isadmin'];

        if(admin == isAdmin){
            admin = 1;

        $.ajax({
            method:'POST',
            url:makeAdminUrl,
            data:{ Admin:admin , userId:userId , _token:token}
        })
        .done(function(msg){
            console.log(msg['Admin']);
        });
    });
```

/////////// html ///////////

```
@extends('cp.master')

@section('title','users')

@section('page-content')

  <div class="row" style="margin-top:20px;">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <table class="table">

        <thead>
          <th>#</th>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Created at</th>
          <th>Action</th>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
          @foreach($users as $user)
            <tr>
              <th>{{ $user->id }}</th>
              <td>{{ $user->username }}</td>
              <td>{{ $user->created_at }}</td>
              <td>
                <a data-isadmin="{{ $user->admin }}" href="#" class="btn btn-primary admin-btn">Admin</a>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger ban-btn">Ban</a>
              </td>
            </tr>
          @endforeach
        </tbody>

      </table>
    </div>
    <div class="text-center">
      {{ $users->links() }}
    </div>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var makeAdminUrl = '{{ route('makeAdmin') }}';
    var token = '{{ Session::token() }}';
  </script>
@endsection




 ////////// my controller //////////

  public function postAdmin(Request $request)
  {
    $user = User::find($request['userId']);
    $user->admin = $request['Admin'];
    $user->update();

    return response()->json(['Admin' => $request['Admin']]);
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assumed your problem as per your description in the question.

Try this example, it may helps you.

Do the necessary changes as per your need.

```js
$('.dummy-class').click(function(){
  //Get the current value, check condition and change the value
  var temp = $(this).text() == 0 ? 1 : 0;
  //Set the new value
  $(this).text(temp)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
A = <a href="#" class="dummy-class">0</a>
B = <a href="#" class="dummy-class">0</a>
C = <a href="#" class="dummy-class">1</a>
```

Comment: It works here but when I did it in my own code it didn't work

Comment: @mahmood Can you create a jsfiddle to check exact problem?

Comment: Please describe the exact problem in your JavaScript

Comment: I want to do what you did  in my code but it didn't work after i did the necessary changes

Comment: Can you update your code or just include JavaScript code in a jsfiddle ?

Comment: Can you console in JS what value is showing when you click on Admin link?

Comment: You can use to apply final value to admin variable like below.
var isAdmin = $(this).attr('data-isadmin') == 0 ? 1 ? 0;
Then again console.log(isAdmin);

Comment: in the console it shows that when I click on Admin link  it changes for once ( if the value is 0 it changes to 1 ) and when I click again it still 1 and when I reload the page  and click again it changes to 0

Comment: When value updates, you need to set the new value to the link.
 var isAdmin = $(this).attr('data-isadmin') == 0 ? 1 ? 0; 
 $(this).attr('data-isadmin', isAdmin);

Comment: @mahmood  See I've edited my code and added comments to see and understand the code, It's simple two lines code.

Comment: I did what you did but the same result

Comment: It seems that your value is not setting on the view again once update.

Comment: hey man Thanks a lot ... you saved my life man I appreciate ...  this works var isAdmin = $(this).attr('data-isadmin') == 0 ? 1 : 0;
$(this).attr('data-isadmin', isAdmin);  ..... do you have any idea why my code didn't work the way this couple of  lines I added

Comment: Your code was not updating the value in the view again, BTW, your welcome, can you accept my answer if it helped you?

Comment: Thanks A lot ... I think I accepted your answer .... but If there is something you need me to do I will but tell me how coz I'm new here... and again Thanks

Comment: Okay, if you need me just let me know, I will try my best to guide you, again your welcome.

Comment: I want to solve this problem if you could .... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39465848/when-i-add-b-tag-in-jquery-in-html-i-get-http-1-1-500-internal-server-erro?noredirect=1