# when I add b tag in jquery ( in html() ) I get HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

This is the code

```
 html
  <a href="#" data-postid="{{ $post->id }}" data-userid="{{ Auth::user()->id }}" class="like-post">
    @if(Auth::user()->likes()->where(['user_id' => Auth::user()->id, 'post_or_comment_id' => $post->id,'isPost' => 1])->first())
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>like
    @else
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty"></span>like
    @endif
  </a>|

jquery
$('.like-post').on('click',function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var userId = event.target.dataset['userid'];
    var postId = event.target.dataset['postid'];

    $.ajax({
        method:'POST',
        url:likeUrl,
        data:{userId:userId, p_or_c:postId, isPost:1, _token:token},
        success:function(msg){
            if(msg['like'] == 0)
                $(event.target).html('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty"></span>like');
            else
                $(event.target).html('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>like');

            console.log(msg['like']+'yes');
        }
    })
});
```

every thing works fine but when I change :

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>like
```

to (in both html and jquery files ):

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span><b>like</b>
or
<b><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>like</b>
```

this happens before adding b tag ... everything fine
[screen shot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h0zwF.png) 
after adding b tag [screen shot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hJg8I.png)

I get this error  HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error 
and I tried many things but it seems that jquery doesn't accept two tags in html()  cause I tried to change b tag to span tag and the same error appears and thanks in advance

Comment: you can also use <strong> tag instead of <b>

Comment: I did but the same thing

Comment: will you please try to put only text content with <b> tag, and check whats the issue is?

Comment: It could be something with your if else clause, try to force it on true or false, maybe your class " -empty doesn't" load or something

Comment: I did <b>like</b>  ..... the same error

Comment: when I remove  if else statement and  apply the same code that works but when I add b tag it doesn't work and the same error

Comment: @Loading..  http://stackoverflow.com/users/6608101/loading  could you help

Comment: @mahmood So the problem is when you append two tags, its showing error, right ?

Comment: @mahmood : could you inspect in the console for Ajax, is responding 200 or not, because I think server has some issues and it responding with 500 Error.

Comment: yeah .... when I do like this <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span><b>like</b> ... but it works when it look like that <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>like

Comment: when I do <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>like it is responding 200

Comment: @mahmood See I've posted one example, that works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$(event.target).append('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span><b>like</b>');
```

I create a jsFiddle for you: [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t927seuw/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this snippet, similar to your example.

When you append an HTML, there is no matter how many tags you include in that. The HTML should be proper, That's it.

```js
$('.like-post').click(function(){
  $(event.target).html("<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-star'></span><b>like</b>");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" data-postid="105" data-userid="505" class="like-post">
  Click
</a>
```

Comment: you mean I have to change '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>like' to  "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-star'></span><b>like</b>"  I did but the same error

Comment: HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error

Comment: in your code  HTTP/1.1 200 OK  but mine is HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error  when using b tag

Comment: Can you comment your ajax call for few mins, and then try with the same. It should work.

Comment: I did it works I mean that every time I click the link it repeats itself

Comment: Do you mean there was problem of recursion ? I don't see any trigger click event called for this code.

Comment: every time I click like it goes like that *like * like *like *like   that happens with every time I click  but  the b tag works

Comment: no it's your code that you told me to try .... I commented the ajax call as you told me

Comment: So what is the problem right now ? Can you show me your jsfiddle to chek

Comment: this happens before adding b tag ...  everything fine http://i.stack.imgur.com/h0zwF.png                                                         after adding b tag http://i.stack.imgur.com/hJg8I.png